# Getting a specific part of a URL

Tags: r, regex

Below are few URL.I want to get a particular number from that URL.

```
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1002638/000100263816000080/exhibit211subsidiarylisting.htm
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1013871/000101387113000003/exhibit21110k2012.htm
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1420800/000142080014000006/exhibit211subsidiariesofth.htm
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1305014/000130501415000119/a9302015exhibit21.htm
```

I want to get the output as below:

```
1002638
1013871
1420800
1305014
```

Can you please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: Try `stringr::str_extract(urls,"(?<=data/)[0-9]+")`

Comment: Thanks Nicola.Can you please explain me the codes ?

Comment: I used a regular expression. If you are not familiar with it, I suggest to start with a tutorial (just google regex tutorial or similar; there are tons of material). In the regular expression I used I said: take the part of the string which is made by one or more consecutive numeric characters (the `[0-9]+` part) which follows `data/` (the `(?<=data/)` part).

Comment: Or maybe extract 7 digit numbers? `library(stringr); str_extract(urlstring, "[0-9]{7}")` ?

Comment: Thank you Nicola for your help.It works. I am not good in regex.Can you refer me a good tutorial to get good knowledge in regex ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
myurl <-c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1002638/000100263816000080/exhibit211subsidiarylisting.htm",
       "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1013871/000101387113000003/exhibit21110k2012.htm", 
       "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1420800/000142080014000006/exhibit211subsidiariesofth.htm", 
       "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1305014/000130501415000119/a9302015exhibit21.htm")

# split each string into substrings, with the backslashes as separators
# then take the seventh element of each result
unlist(lapply(myurl, function(u) strsplit(u, "/")[[1]][7]))

"1002638" "1013871" "1420800" "1305014"
```

Comment: This is much slower than the solution I proposed in the comments. Furthermore, you should declare the packages you are using (`%>%` is not base R). Actually, you shouldn't use external packages when they are not needed (as here).

Comment: good idea, I hate answers that depend on external packages when not needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Read file with `sep = "/"`, then get relevant column:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1002638/000100263816000080/exhibit211subsidiarylisting.htm
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1013871/000101387113000003/exhibit21110k2012.htm
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1420800/000142080014000006/exhibit211subsidiariesofth.htm
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1305014/000130501415000119/a9302015exhibit21.htm
                  ", sep = "/")


df1$V7
# [1] 1002638 1013871 1420800 1305014
```